# Wordpress: Adding Security

Tags: htaccess, security, wp-debug

Regarding this answer, is correct to add the file debug.log in this way?

```
RewriteRule (?:debug|readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html|log?) - [R=404,NC,L]
```

Kind Regards

Comment: "is correct to add the file debug.log in this way?"- Do you mean in terms of modifying that directive? Well, it depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve. If you simply want to "hide" `debug.log` from HTTP access then that directive arguably does _too much_. Since there are no anchors on the regex it could potentially conflict with valid URLs - depending on where you place the directive in your `.htaccess` file. Then again, it could do exactly what you require.

Comment: Yes, basically debug.log, but without deny, with 404. May you suggest me a rule less "too much" please?

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, basically debug.log, but without deny, with 404

Yes, that directive will serve a "404 Not Found" when attempting to request `debug.log`.

> `|log?`

However, because of the `?` in the above regex, it will also block `debug.lo`. Is that intentional? In fact, if that is intentional then you could simply remove the `g?` part - since it serves no purpose. But if not, then remove the trailing `?` to match `debug.log` only.

However, it also potentially blocks any URL that simply contains `debug.log` in the URL-path (since there are no anchors `^` or `$` or *word boundaries* on the regex). For example, the following *innocent* URL(s) will also be blocked if the directive appears *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
/what-is-the-meaning-of-debug.log-on-my-filesystem
/are-changelog.md-files-really-necessary
```

(Should you have articles with such a title/slug.)

For this reason, this directive should probably be located at the *end* of the `.htaccess` file, *after* the WordPress front-controller, so that you only block access to physical files. This will also be marginally more efficient.

`[R=404,NC,L]` - minor point... the `L` flag is not strictly required here. `L` is *implied* when specifying a non-3xx return code.

---

To simply block (with a 404) requests for `debug.log` (all lowercase) in the document root only then the following would be sufficient:

```
RewriteRule ^debug\.log$ - [R=404]
```